# Mongo node-JS driver: group, sort, and limit query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a dataset within Mongo which I am trying to query via the Node JS driver. Specifically, I am trying to group by a field (Domain), sort by date (DTG), and then limit to the 1 record (the latest record).

An example of the data:

```
{'Domain':'google.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 16, 23, 2, 920000)}
{'Domain':'google.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 15, 16, 23, 2, 920000)}
{'Domain':'google.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 12, 16, 23, 2, 920000)}
{'Domain':'yahoo.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 16, 27, 41, 714000)}
{'Domain':'yahoo.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 16, 27, 41, 714000)}
{'Domain':'yahoo.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 10, 16, 27, 41, 714000)}
{'Domain':'bing.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 16, 27, 43, 714000)}
```

The output I am trying to get would be:

```
{'Domain':'google.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 16, 23, 2, 920000)}
{'Domain':'yahoo.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 16, 27, 41, 714000)}
{'Domain':'bing.com', 'DTG': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 16, 27, 43, 714000)}
```

I've been trawling the Mongo Node driver documentation, and have been trying to use the $group operator, but so far have been unsuccessful.

Comment: he is trying to group with Domain.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK. Agree that this is answered already. Thanks for your help. My final code which works is:

db.collection('test').aggregate([{"$sort":{"DTG":-1}},{"$group":{"_id":"$Domain", "DTG":{"$first":"$DTG"}, "ID":{"$first":"$_id"}}}])